# Timeout while waiting for response in request-response pattern

Tags: c#, .net-core, masstransit

I am trying to setup request-response pattern with MassTransit and RabbitMq. Request is delivered to the consumer, RespondAsync succeeds but GetResponse on client side hangs forever and finally it times out. What I am doing wrong? It seems everything is configured correctly on RabbitMQ side (see screens below).

Here is how I add mass transit on "service-server":

```cs
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using MassTransit;

namespace Airstrike.Backend.GroupService.Service
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                    {
                        x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

                        var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

                        x.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);

                        x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                        {
                            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                        });
                    });

                    services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true);
                });
    }
}
```

and here is how my consumer / consumer definition looks like:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransit.ConsumeConfigurators;
using MassTransit.Definition;
using Airstrike.Backend.GroupService.ServiceContract.Actions.CreateGroup;

namespace Airstrike.Backend.GroupService.Service.Actions.CreateGroup
{
    public class CreateGroupAction :
        IConsumer<ICreateGroupPayload>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ICreateGroupPayload> consumeContext)
        {
            await consumeContext.RespondAsync<ICreateGroupResult>(new
            {
                GroupGuid = Guid.NewGuid()
            });
        }
    }

    public class CreateGroupActionDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<CreateGroupAction>
    {
        public CreateGroupActionDefinition()
        {
            EndpointName = "group-service";
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how it looks like on "service-client" side:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Airstrike.Backend.GraphqlPublicGateway.Services;
using Airstrike.Backend.GroupService.ServiceContract.Actions.CreateGroup;
using GraphQL.Server.Ui.Altair;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using GraphQL.Server;
using MassTransit;

namespace Airstrike.Backend.GraphqlPublicGateway
{
    using Schema;
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IGroupService, Services.GroupService>();
            
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    
                });
                x.AddRequestClient<ICreateGroupPayload>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here how I call service (from service-client):

```cs
using System;
using Airstrike.Backend.GroupService.ServiceContract.Actions.CreateGroup;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit;

namespace Airstrike.Backend.GraphqlPublicGateway.Services
{
    public class GroupService : IGroupService
    {
        private readonly IRequestClient<ICreateGroupPayload> _createGroupClient;
        
        public GroupService(
            IRequestClient<ICreateGroupPayload> createGroupClient)
        {
            _createGroupClient = createGroupClient;
        }
        
        public async Task<ICreateGroupResult> CreateGroup(ICreateGroupPayload payload)
        {
            var response = await _createGroupClient.GetResponse<ICreateGroupResult>(new
            {
                Name = payload.Name,
                Description = payload.Description
            });

            return response.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you're starting the bus on the service client side. Why didn't you use the same `AddMassTransitHostedService` as you did in the service server application?

> Always, always start the bus.

From the documentation [Requests](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/requests.html#request-client-configuration) section:

> The bus must always be started, so if the hosted service is not included, be sure to start the bus manually using IBusControl.